# Java: Direct constructor in abstract class

Tags: java, class, constructor, abstract

I'm trying to set up an abstract class with 6 variables, and a constructor inside that class, that would populate these fields for every new created object.

What I have now is

```
public abstract class AbstractUser {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String fullName;
    private String email;
    private char sex;
    private Date birthday;

    public AbstractUser(String username, String password, String fullName, String email, char sex, Date birthday){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.email = email;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error "The type AbstractUser is already defined".

I would like that it populates the fields with data set from another concrete class, like

```
AbstractUser User1 = new AbstractUser("John", "john567", "John Evans", "john@msn.com", "m", 123456789);
```

Is that even possible with an abstract class?

Comment: This doesn't look like your complete code. Please make sure your entire file is here, and post the complete error message. No, you can't instantiate `AbstractUser`; that's exactly what `abstract` means.

Comment: Well much more than that isn't there in my code. I am starting to make a simple user management program. The first thing I wanted to make is an abstract class that saves all the data required for every user, abstract because there will be types of users. Well anyways an requirement is that inside of the abstract class, I need to implement an constructor that would directly populate variables, which I've stated above in the post.

Comment: Okay, but the code you've posted won't produce that error.

Comment: This is unbelievable.. After I created a new project, and a new class with the same content the error is gone.. Well I have no idea how that happened.

Comment: Anyways, is it possible to do the constructor inside an abstract class thing I've previously mentioned? That'd be great!

Comment: You may have had multiple copies. Yes, it's entirely standard to have a constructor just like the one you have now, but you can't call `new AbstractUser`; you have to subclass it and then instantiate a concrete subclass. Your subclass will have to call `super(username, password...)`.

Comment: So you mean something like 
public class RegUser extends AbstractUser{
  super("user", "pass"...);
}
Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize an abstract class.  You need to `extend` your abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

We can have constructor inside Abstract class but we can't create an object of an abstract class.